# Spring Security authentication for a REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, security

At the moment a basic `REST API` has 3 URL's (not actual URL's)

1. http://localhost:8080/app
2. http://localhost:8080/app/home
3. http://localhost:8080/app/product

Currently all three URL's have basic authentication using `Spring Security` using XML.

However, I would like to remove the basic authentication for URL 1.

I have unsuccessfully tried the following the following approaches (reduced XML)

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```

vs

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```

Is there something I'm missing in my configuration or there is another way to achieve this using `Spring Security`?

Comment: Not sure I understand you Kayaman - this is a basic WAR. The context path is  **app**  .. i.e. the WAR is **app.war**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the context path of your server to 'app' so all the paths in your application will be `localhost:8080/app/**`.

If you want to allow everyone to access all the paths in the application and only for authenticated users to access `/home` and `/product` you should do this:

```
<http>
 <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
 <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/product" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
 <http-basic/>
</http>
```

This way everyone will get to `localhost:8080/app` but only `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` users will access to `/home` & `/product`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing something like this:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```

Comment: I tried that Vishal but no authentication is applied to any URL when I tried that approach unfortunately.

Comment: Can you move your "/app" response to "/app/{something}"? That would quickly solve your problem without any design changes. You can redirect your "/app" to "/app/{something}"

Comment: Unfortunately no  Vishal as its a legacy published API and I cant change the URL structure

Comment: Then I would suggest you to explore "AuthenticationProvider". This would help you give a complete customized solution as per your need. Register this in your spring configuration and put these constraints in "authenticate" method. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Vishal I tried looking at looking extending the AuthenticationProvider but having problems reading the actual URL path using that approach. I'm very surprised you that is not possible with spring security to mark an URL as requiring no authentication